# How to get names of approvers from sql query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two Sql Server 2012 tables, "Person" and "Report". A description of each table is listed below:

Person table (Column name: data type):

```
PersonID: bigint
Prefix: tinyint
FirstName: nvarchar(50)
LastName: nvarchar(50)
Suffix: nvarchar(15)
JobTitle: nvarchar(50)
WorkPhoneNumber: nvarchar(25)
Email: nvarchar(50)
```

Note: The "`Prefix`" column in the Person table refers to another table named "`SupportCategory`"; this numerical value corresponds to a "Mr.", "Ms."...etc.

Report table (Column name: data type):

```
ReportID: bigint
ReportName: nvarchar(150)
ExecutiveApproved: bigint
ManagerApproved: bigint
StaffApproved: bigint
LegalApproved: bigint
AccountingApproved: bigint
ReportStorageDirectory: nvarchar(100)
CreatedBy: bigint
CreatedDAte: DateTime
```

Could you specify the query that I would need to get the full name in the format "`[LastName] + ' ' + ISNULL([Suffix], '') + ', ' + [Prefix] + ' ' + [FirstName]`" for "`ExecutiveApproved, ManagerApproved, StaffApproved, LegalApproved, AccountingApproved, and CreatedBy`"? The desired result is listed below:

```
|ReportID|ReportName|ExecutiveApproved|ManagerApproved|StaffApproved|LegalApproved|AccountingApproved|CreatedBy|CreatedDate
```

Comment: **Remark:** You have a lot of fields like **[xxxApproved]**. This makes it complicated, and you might get problems in future, when new types are needed. You could improve your design by creating a separate table which holds **ReportID, PersonID, FunctionID** - and FunctionID would then link to Executive, Manager, etc.  This way, you are much more flexible, and your queries would also be more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple joins:

```
select r.ReportID,
       r.ReportName,
       p1.LastName + ' ' + ISNULL(c1.Suffix, '') + ', ' + c1.Code + ' ' + p1.FirstName as ExecutiveApproved,
       p2.LastName + ' ' + ISNULL(c2.Suffix, '') + ', ' + c2.Code + ' ' + p2.FirstName as ManagerApproved,
       p3.LastName + ' ' + ISNULL(c3.Suffix, '') + ', ' + c3.Code + ' ' + p3.FirstName as StaffApproved,
       p4.LastName + ' ' + ISNULL(c4.Suffix, '') + ', ' + c4.Code + ' ' + p4.FirstName as LegalApproved,
       p5.LastName + ' ' + ISNULL(c5.Suffix, '') + ', ' + c5.Code + ' ' + p5.FirstName as AccountingApproved,
       r.CreatedBy,
       r.CreatedDate 
from reports r
left join persons p1 on r.ExecutiveApproved = p1.PersonID
left join persons p2 on r.ManagerApproved = p2.PersonID
left join persons p3 on r.StaffApproved = p3.PersonID
left join persons p4 on r.LegalApproved= p4.PersonID
left join persons p5 on r.AccountingApproved = p5.PersonID
left join SupportCategory c1 on p1.Prefix = c1.Prefix 
left join SupportCategory c2 on p2.Prefix = c2.Prefix 
left join SupportCategory c3 on p3.Prefix = c3.Prefix 
left join SupportCategory c4 on p4.Prefix = c4.Prefix 
left join SupportCategory c5 on p5.Prefix = c5.Prefix
```

Comment: I tried Giorgi's approach, but I received the following error: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ', ' to data type int.

Comment: @PublicTechie2015, yes there shoud be some code column from prefixcategory, I have edited.

Comment: Giorgi, I think I resolved the error that I was getting. I'm testing now.

Comment: Giorgi, Your solution works beautifully. Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're basically going to have to do a series of JOINs from the Report table to the Person, one for each column that you want to convert to a name. Use LEFT JOIN, because each joined copy of Person will only match one of the columns. In order to join the same table multiple times, you'll have to alias it. Then you use the aliases to select names. The basic form will be something like this:

```
SELECT ReportID, ReportName, 
  (executive.LastName + ' ' + ISNULL([executive.Suffix], '') + ', ' + executive.Prefix + ' ' + executive.FirstName) AS ExecutiveName, 
  <repeat for each of the other columns>
  FROM Report
  LEFT JOIN Person as executive ON Person.id = Report.ExecutiveApproved
  <repeat for each of the other columns>
```